# how to get variable of one class in another extended class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

in below test script I want to pass value of `suiteResult` from class `SuiteOneBase`  to  class `SuiteOneCaseOne` .How can i do this. Suppose if I am getting `suiteResult =true` then  i should get true in class `SuiteOneCaseOne` . But now `everytime` i am getting false only

First class

```
public class SuiteOneBase extends SuiteBase{ 
  boolean suiteResult;
@BeforeSuite
    public void checkSuiteToRun() throws IOException{
        init();
        //To set TestSuiteList.xls file's path In FilePath Variable.
        FilePath = TestSuiteListExcel;
        SheetName = "SuitesList";
        SuiteName = "SuiteOne";
        ToRunColumnName = "SuiteToRun";
        suiteResult= SuiteUtility.checkToRunUtility(FilePath, SheetName,ToRunColumnName,SuiteName);

          if(!suiteResult){ 

            SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath, SheetName, "Skipped/Executed", SuiteName, "TestSuite Skipped");
                throw new SkipException(SuiteName+"'s SuiteToRun Flag Is 'N' Or Blank. So Skipping Execution Of "+SuiteName);
        }
        SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath, SheetName, "Skipped/Executed", SuiteName, "TestSuite Executed");

    }   
}
```

Second Class

```
 public class SuiteOneCaseOne extends SuiteOneBase{

        @BeforeTest
        public void checkCaseToRun() throws IOException{


            System.out.println("suiteResult "+suiteResult );
            if(!suiteResult){
            if(!SuiteUtility.checkToRunUtility(FilePath, SheetName,ToRunColumnNameTestCase,TestCaseName)){

                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath, SheetName, "Pass/Fail/Skip", TestCaseName, "TESTCASE SKIP");

                throw new SkipException(TestCaseName+"'s CaseToRun Flag Is 'N' Or Blank. So Skipping Execution Of "+TestCaseName);
            }   
            }

            TestDataToRun = SuiteUtility.checkToRunUtilityOfData(FilePath, TestCaseName, ToRunColumnNameTestData);

        }
```

SuiteBase

```
package com.stta.TestSuiteBase;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.stta.utility.Read_XLS;

public class SuiteBase {    
    public static Read_XLS TestSuiteListExcel=null;
    public static Read_XLS TestCaseListExcelOne=null;
    public static Read_XLS TestCaseListExcelTwo=null;

    public void init() throws IOException{

    TestSuiteListExcel = new Read_XLS(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\stta\\ExcelFiles\\TestSuiteList.xls");

    TestCaseListExcelOne = new Read_XLS(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\stta\\ExcelFiles\\SuiteOne.xls");

        TestCaseListExcelTwo = new Read_XLS(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\com\\stta\\ExcelFiles\\SuiteTwo.xls");                                                                           

}
}
```

Comment: Can you post SuiteBase too?

Comment: if both the classes are in same package then there it is already available..just use super keyword and see what all variables and methods are accessible

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ITestContext](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestContext.html) for that purpose:

```
public class SuiteOneBase extends SuiteBase { 

    @BeforeSuite
    public void checkSuiteToRun(ITestContext context) throws IOException {
        // [...]
        boolean suiteResult = SuiteUtility.checkToRunUtility(FilePath, SheetName,ToRunColumnName,SuiteName);    
        // [...]
        context.setAttribute("suiteResult", suiteResult);    
    }   
}
```

And

```
public class SuiteOneCaseOne extends SuiteOneBase {

    @BeforeTest
    public void checkCaseToRun(ITestContext context) throws IOException {    
        boolean suiteResult = context.getAttribute("suiteResult");
        System.out.println("suiteResult "+suiteResult );
        // [...]    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,I used above solution but I am getting  error "Type mismatched: cannot convert  object to boolean" in line  boolean suiteResult = context.getAttribute("suiteResult");.And when i type caste to boolean it giving result as null

Comment: "Type mismatched: cannot convert object to boolean" is due to null to boolean convertion. The question is why the attribute is not in the context (null).

Answer (score 0):

You should create suiteResult public or protected variable of class SuiteOneBase

```
  public  boolean suiteResult;
  or
  protected  boolean suiteResult;
```

Hope this will work!!

Comment: No, this is wrong. SuiteOneCaseOne can *already* see SuiteOneBase's `suiteResult` as they are in the same package, so there's no need for any modifier.

Answer (score 0):

`SuiteOneCaseOne` extends `SuiteOneBase` and is in the same package, so it can **already** see the package-level `suiteResult`. No need for any additional passing.

The `@BeforeSuite` in `SuiteOneBase` runs **before** the `@BeforeTest` in `SuiteOneCaseOne`, so the fact that the latter sees `suiteResult == false` proves that the former - which must have run - must have explicitly set `suiteResult = false`.

You're not looking at a default value, or the value of a different field. `checkSuiteToRun()` must run, and there are no exceptions or returns, so:

```
suiteResult= SuiteUtility.checkToRunUtility(FilePath, SheetName,ToRunColumnName,SuiteName);
```

... must have returned false.

(And yet you don't mention the tests failing to run as a result of the `SkipException`. I don't know how that can be avoided. Unless perhaps your `@BeforeSuite` has been imported from the wrong package, i.e. it doesn't actually get run.)